# Firefox adding www when trying to resolve a domain

Tags: firefox, domain

I'm trying to reach `api.example.com`, but when I do Firefox says:

```
Couldn't resolve server www.api.example.com
```

What is going on? Why is Firefox adding the `www` by itself?

It works fine in Chrome, Safari and even on Firefox on another computer, so there must be something wrong with my local copy.

Comment: yes, im developing the api. It works in the code but i want to test it in my webbrowser aswell.

Answer (score 7):

This feature is controlled by the three preferences `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled`, `browser.fixup.alternate.prefix` and `browser.fixup.alternate.suffix` that you can see if you type `about:config` into the location bar. By default, if Firefox cannot resolve the server name that has been typed into the location bar it will try to "fix" it. In order to do it it will try to prepend the name with the prefix "www." and/or append the suffix ".com". Chrome has a different strategy towards "fixing" incomplete names - it will simply start a Google search.

Comment: Thanks! This was one part of the solution. This alone did not work, i had to clear my complete browser history in order to make it not add the "www.". Stupid feature

Comment: @Martin: Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: I also tried all the options, but the only thing that worked was: Options > Privacy & Security > tick only Cached Web Content and clear that.  The issue was caused by a deployment issue that temporarily messed up the redirect structure in my web.config and it looks like Firefox cached the wrong redirect.

Answer (score 1):

What I believe Firefox will do is, if you type in `api.example.com`, look for that first.  If it can't resolve it, it will then try adding the `www.` on the front, as so many websites (although a decreasing number) have hostnames where the `www` subdomain is needed to resolve their IP address.

Comment: It works in Google Chrome and firefox on another computer. I can also ping api.example.com and get a response so firefox should be able to resolve it

Comment: Have you tried downloading [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) and seeing whether Firefox is actually requesting and getting a response from `api.example.com`?

Comment: not requesting a thing. Firebug shows a GET to www.api.example.com which is aborted instantly since it cant resolve www.api.example.com cause it doesnt exist.

Comment: Then it looks like Firefox can't resolve `api.example.com`, if that's what's being entered in the location bar.

Comment: i enter api.example.com but its trying to resolve www.api.example.com